# Android Studio Single activity acting as many

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-button

I have looked everywhere but don't seem to be able to find what I am looking for. I have an activity with multiple buttons, each button opens a new activity with an identical recyclerview layout, but different data. I am wondering if it is possible to use one activity and layout instead of multiple? this way instead of having 10+ activities (one for each button) I only have to manage one when a button is clicked and simply pass the necessary list data to it.

I believe you could set the intents for each button to call the same activity but with an integer such as 1-10, in the activity it takes the value and decides which list should be presented? If anyone thinks of how this could be done or a simpler way I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Why don't you just update current RecyclerView? Just reset the content and add new.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are various ways to do that.

1. You could use multiple fragments on the same activity. Then add/remove fragments on each button click.
2. You can have multiple layouts within your activity. Say you have two buttons, and you have three layouts `layout1`, `layout2`, `layout3`, sequentially one after the another. So if initially, `layout1` is visible and the rest are gone using `layout.setVisiblity(View.GONE)`, if you click `button1`, ypu can do `layout1.setVisiblity(View.GONE); layout3.setVisiblity(View.GONE); layout2.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)` and vice-versa for pressing `button2`.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the activities opened by the buttons similar? If so, you could only take care of the changes in the elements of the layout & specify conditions.

For instance, if you click a button, instead of changing the whole thing, you only go into the buttons & change their texts with `btn.setText("...")`. You could define different conditional statements inside the onClickListener of that button. 
It could be something like:

```
if(btn.getText().equals("a certain text that you set to the button")){
    doSomething();
else if(btn.getText().equals("another option")){
    doSomethingElse();
```

Following this logic, you could continually update the elements in your layout & your code will decide what to do depending on what's stored in these elements.

The second option that comes to my mind would be creating different xml layout files & simply changing the layout of your MainActivity to the appropriate one depending on what stage of your process you are at.

I hope this helps,